# How to assess whether r-squared for a regression model differs between two groups?

Tags: r, regression, r-squared, qq-plot

I have two values for $R^2$. One is for a control group (.713) and the other an experimental group (.527). The regression model is the same in both groups.

How can I determine whether this difference is statistically significant?